# Remove pattern from string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working on a tool, which helps me to analyze a constantly growing `String`, that can look like this: `String s = "AAAAAAABBCCCDDABQ"`. What I want to do is to find a sequence of A's and B's, do something and then remove that sequence from the original `String`.

My code looks like this:

```
while (someBoolean){

    if(Pattern.matches("A+B+", s)) {
        //Do stuff
        //Remove the found pattern
    }

    if(Pattern.matches("C+D+", s)) {
        //Do other stuff
        //Remove the found pattern
    }

}
return s;
```

Also, how I could remove the three sequences, so that `s` just contains `"Q"` at the end of the calculation, without and endless loop?

Comment: Yes but you can create a copy of the string and store it in a mutable local variable.

Comment: I expressed myself unclear, sorry. 
I have somewhere in my code a function which periodically adds characters with "+=" at the end of my String, thats what I meant with "growing".

Comment: @schande Is there a pattern to this String or does it just add random letters?

Comment: @Tommy There are patterns, and I try to describe them with the regex syntax. I am looking for patterns like: AB AAB AAAB ABB ABBB..., which i try to describe with "A+B+". An other pattern would be "A+O+C+"

Comment: You probably should check existence of particular character when adding it to the string. Do you work somehow with the string containing multiple 'AA's ?

Comment: @schande so you want to remove all of the _duplicate_ letters from the `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a regex replacement loop, i.e. the methods [`appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and [`appendTail(StringBuffer sb)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-).

To find one of many patterns, use the [`|` regex matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical), and capture each pattern separately.

You can then use [`group(int group)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) to get the matched string for each capture group (first group is group 1), which returns `null` if that group didn't match. For better performance, to simply check whether the group matched, use [`start(int group)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start-int-), which returns `-1` if that group didn't match.

Example:

```
String s = "AAAAAAABBCCCDDABQ";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(A+B+)|(C+D+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.start(1) != -1) { // Group 1 found
        System.out.println("Found AB: " + m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(buf, ""); // Replace matched substring with ""
    } else if (m.start(2) != -1) { // Group 2 found
        System.out.println("Found CD: " + m.group(2));
        m.appendReplacement(buf, ""); // Replace matched substring with ""
    }
}
m.appendTail(buf);
String remain = buf.toString();
System.out.println("Remain: " + remain);
```

*Output*

```
Found AB: AAAAAAABB
Found CD: CCCDD
Found AB: AB
Remain: Q
```

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could up vote it 3 times, because That's what it deserves.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the string always ends in Q.

```
String s="AAAAAAABBCCCDDABQ";

Pattern abPattern = Pattern.compile("A+B+");
Pattern cdPattern = Pattern.compile("C+D+");


while (s.length() > 1){

    Matcher abMatcher = abPattern.matcher(s);
    if (abMatcher.find()) {
        s = abMatcher.replaceFirst("");
        //Do other stuff
    }

    Matcher cdMatcher = cdPattern.matcher(s);
    if (cdMatcher.find()) {
      s = cdMatcher.replaceFirst("");
        //Do other stuff
    }

}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: If you assume the String always ends in Q you can just do `s = s.substring(s.length()-1);` Same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
String input = "AAAAAAABBCCCDDABQ";
String result = input;
String[] chars = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}; // chars to replace

for (String ch : chars) {
    if (result.contains(ch)) {
        String pattern = "[" + ch + "]+";
        result = result.replaceAll(pattern, ch);
    }
}

System.out.println(input); //"AAAAAAABBCCCDDABQ"
System.out.println(result); //"ABCDABQ"
```

This basically replace sequence of each character for single one.

If you want to remove the sequence completely, just replace `ch` to `""` in `replaceAll` method parameters inside if body.